# Changing the size of columns in a JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

I am creating a GUI program and I need a table with different sized columns. How do I change it so that the 1st column is smaller than the 2nd and 3rd column?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get a handle to the `TableColumnModel`, and from there you are able to set the individual column widths.  For example:

```
JTable tbl = new JTable();
TableColumnModel colMdl = tbl.getColumnModel();
colMdl.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
colMdl.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
colMdl.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

Also, here's some useful [example code](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/PackCol.html) showing how to "pack" a given column to be wide enough to show all values in the `JTable`.  I typically use a modified version of this in my GUIs and will "pack" the table when the first row is added to it - After this I allow the user to control the widths.

Comment: when I try and compile, it says cannot find symbol - class TableColumnModel

Comment: You'll need to import it at the top of your .java file: import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel.

Comment: I've got import javax.swing.*;
It worked when I did 
DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel)table.getColumnModel();
Is that right? 
When I try to set it to a really small width like 5, the columns become the same width again. Is that too small?

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast the column model to a DefaultTableColumnModel; all the methods you need are on the TableColumnModel interface.  You can either explicitly import this (as I mentioned above or import javax.swing.table.* as well as javax.swing.*).  Regarding the sizing issues you may need to set the minimum width to 0 (setMinWidth method) as well as the preferred width.

Comment: Try setting the autoresize of the columns off:

JTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Swing tutorial yet? All you questions are basic and are covered in the tutorial.

You will find the tutorial has a working example that does exactly this. We should not have to spend time reminding you to read the tutorial FIRST before posting a question.

"Teach somebody to fish and they eat for life. Give somebody a fish and they eat for a day."

(and then they come back and ask another question, which is why spoonfeeding answers is not a good idea.)